# Show there is no function from $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ with $f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$ and $f(z)^n=z$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $n\geq 2$ be a natural number. There is no function $f : \mathbb{C}^*\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^*$ with the two properties
$f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$ for all $z,w\in\mathbb{C}^*$, and
$(f(z))^n=z$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}^*\quad (n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the first condition, $f(1)=1$ and thus
$$
1 = f(1) = f((e^{2\pi i/n})^n)=f(e^{2\pi i/n})^n ,
$$
but this contradicts the second requirement.

Comment: Far too long an answer..Can you trim a couple of pages off?